# Rewinding CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Let say I have a div

```
<div id='animate'></div>
```

and has an animation of:

```
@keyframes move{
  from{transform:translateX(500px);}
  to{transform:translateX(0px);}
}
```

And i have a button that when clicked will programatically set the animationDirection to reverse. But what happen is that it restart the animation and execute the animation in reverse. What I really want is reverse the animation from its current state(before the animation ends) without restarting.

Is that possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/fdZKw/

Answer (score 1):

keyframe animations require a from (0%) and a to (100%) parameters, so unless you set these parameters on the fly via javascript, I don't think you can make it happen. Although, the `transition` property does what you want - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

I have applied it to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fdZKw/1/

```
#animate{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#0099CC;
    transition:transform 5s;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 5s;
}

#animate.go {
    transform:translateX(500px);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(500px);
}
```